# How to solve this inequality :

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

Do you know what is this problem or how to solve it ?
Let $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $x+y+z=1$. Proove that 
$$\frac{(xy+yz+zx+1)(3x^3+3y^3+3z^3+1)}{9(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)}\ge\left(\frac{x\sqrt{x+1}}{\sqrt[4]{9x^2+3}}+\frac{y\sqrt{y+1}}{\sqrt[4]{9y^2+3}}+\frac{z\sqrt{z+1}}{\sqrt[4]{9z^2+3}}\right)^2.$$

My attempts:

Let $a=\sqrt[4]{x^2+3}$, $b=\sqrt[4]{y^2+3}$, $c=\sqrt[4]{z^2+3}$ but it seems useless

Thanks a lot  !

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: I tried to substitute but i didn't worked...

Comment: Show, what exactly you tried. Post your attempts.

Comment: Let $a=\sqrt[4]{x^2+3}$
$b=\sqrt[4]{y^2+3}$
$c=\sqrt[4]{z^2+3}$
but it seems useless

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right you used homogenization and assumption $x+y+z=3$.

Now use C-S:
$$\sqrt[4]{x^2+3}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(1+3)(x^2+3)}}\geq\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(x+3)}.$$
Also, use Holder: $$9(x^3+y^3+z^3)\geq(x+y+z)^3.$$
After this you'll get something obvious:
$$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2(x+y)\geq0.$$

Comment: Which homogenization and assumption
and what about the LHS ?
You meant $x+y+z=1$ no ?

Comment: @Warguarust I mean $x+y+z=3$, of course. How you got $\sqrt[4]{x^2+3}$ from $\sqrt[4]{9x^2+3}$?

Comment: Oh okay i meant $\sqrt[4]{9x^2+3}$

Comment: @Warguarust Now I see that you really did not try to solve this problem. I am ready to help you, but you need to try and to show your attempts. Do it!

Comment: Its cause i have no idea how to solve it...